# java string subsitutions using object

Tags: java, freemarker, ognl

Output of the below code is :

This is Raja from **${Address.Street}** i did my **${Education.degree}** from **${Education.university}**

but what I need is

This is **Raja** from **Namakkal** i did my **B.E** from **Anna University**

is it possible to achieve by using `Freemarker`, `OGNL` or by using `spring`.

```
    public class Test 
    {   
     public static void main(String arg[]) throws TemplateModelException
      {

        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Map<String, Object> address = new HashMap<String, Object>();             

        address.put("Street", "Namakkal");     

        Qualification qualification = new Test.Qualification();    

        map.put("Name", "Raja");
        map.put("Address", address);
        map.put("Education", qualification);


        StrSubstitutor strsub = new StrSubstitutor(map);

        String str = "This is ${Name} from ${Address.Street} i did my ${Education.degree} from ${Education.university}";

        System.out.println(strsub.replace(str));
    }

    public static class Qualification
    {
        public String getDegree()
        {
            return "B.E";
        }

        public String getUniversity()
        {
            return "Anna University";
        }
    }
}
```

please explain the simplest and effective way to achieve this.

Comment: Where is the class `StrSubstitutor`?

Comment: Java enum is good option for you rather than static inner class.

Comment: StrSubstitutor is from org.apache.commons.lang.text.StrSubstitutor; @merlin2011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with freemarker, using the [StringTemplateLoader](http://freemarker.org/docs/api/freemarker/cache/StringTemplateLoader.html) class. This class allows you to create templates from Strings, instead of reading them from files.

Comment: Thank you. it works for me.
Template t = new Template("Vicky", new StringReader(str), new Configuration());
Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out);
t.process(map, out);

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use StrSubstitutor itself, you could try using a custom variable resolver by extending the StrLookUp class.

Example:

```
StrSubstitutor strsub = new StrSubstitutor(new CustomLookUp(map));

...
...

private static class CustomLookUp extends StrLookup<Object> {

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public CustomLookUp(Map<String, Object> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    @Override
    public String lookup(String key) {
       // ...
       // Logic for resolving your variables.
       // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I quite like this answer in principle -- it's essentially just a bit of regular expression work and not terribly many lines of code to solve this problem, so there's really no need for a fancy framework. On the other hand, it would probably be helpful to the OP to expand on what a sample implementation actually might be.

Answer (score 0):

Without freemarker you can use the following:

```
String str="This is "+(String)map.get("Name")+" from "+((Map)map.get("Address")).get("Street")+". I did my "+((Qualification)map.get("Education")).getDegree()+" from "+((Qualification)map.get("Education")).getUniversity()+".";
```

Answer (score 0):

@Anoop example implementation with spring reflection

```
    @Override
    public String lookup(String key) {
        String[] keys = key.split("\\.");
        Object obj = map.get(keys[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < keys.length; i++) {
            Class<?> clazz = obj.getClass();
            Field field = null;
            try {
                field = org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.findField(clazz, (keys[i]));
                org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
                obj = field.get(obj);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return (String) obj;
    }
```